# Cannot launch simulated executable: no file found at /users/.../.xctest file (Xcode 13.1, iOS 11.6)

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests

I ran to an error for a few weeks now and couldn't find any solution.
When I tried to run a test file, the build was complete but it seems when run to the simulator (I am using any iphone), it prints out:

```
Cannot launch simulated executable: no file found at /users/.../.xctest
Domain: IDEFoundationErrorDomain
Code: 1
User Info: { 
IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
```

I tried cleaning the Derived data, clean build, even re - cloning and rebuild the whole file but no luck. Anyone with the same issue?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "I am using any phone". What is your build destination?

Comment: I tried using all types of iPhone (8, X, 11, 12, and 13 including the Pros) @DavidNedrow